# Sublime Text - Shortcut to move cursor to "found" text?

Tags: find, command, sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, text-cursor

Does anyone know a keyboard shortcut to move your cursor position to highlighted "found" text?

Ex: I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type "foo", this will bring me to the first instance of foo in the document.

Now I want a keyboard command to place my cursor next to this instance of foo so I can edit the text that is next to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I don't get your problem, but that's really much the default behaviour.

Anyway, I recommend incremental find (default keybinding is `ctrl+i`).
It searches from the current position and the panel is closed afterwards (which is what I want all of the time).
If you press `escape` in the search bar, the cursor does not move. If you press `enter` it jumps right to the next occurence.

Comment: `escape` is exactly what I was looking for--it makes the cursor active next to the highlighted incremental search result. Simple solution I had not thought of.

Comment: The better behavior, however, is to select the found characters and place the cursor at the end of the selection. This allows many efficient text editing options. We will have to wait until the author discovers that this is indeed what would give the most programmers the most options and chooses to implement it. Leaving the cursor off-screen serves no fruitful purpose whatever and is in fact an effective way of causing editing errors.

Comment: The author has implemented this behavior for Ctrl/Command + g. It seems he could make Ctrl/Command + f behave the same. Alt/Option + g to go to a line has a third behavior. When pressing Esc, back you go to not the line you wanted to go to, while Enter takes you to the line. No keypress or click other than Enter will dismiss the line number box, which is placed at the top, rather than the bottom.

Comment: Just to add to this, a nice workflow is `Command + F`, enter until you find what you need, `Command + i`, `Enter`

Comment: If you have to enter a find string, this is the fastest way. But if you're searching for something you can select, then a much faster solution is: select text; `Cmd+E` to populate the cross-app find pasteboard; `Cmd+G` until you find the string. (This works in any application, by the way.)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to put a cursor at each instance of found text in Sublime Text 3

1. CMD + F  to search for text
2. click the `Find All` button on the right side of the find bar (bottom right of window)
   [image]
3. You should then have an active cursor at the end of each found string of text

Answer (score 0):

On the mac it's command G.Windows, maybe ctrl G?

Comment: Command+G finds the next instance of your term, but still does not make the cursor active next to the place where it finds the text. I'm trying on a mac.